# How to add animation on react-chartjs-2 ? Like Crash Game?

Tags: animation, linechart, react-chartjs-2

I need to develop crash game, so i am using react-chartjs-2 NPM and run the graph successfully.

But our client ask to animate the graph line, like add gif image on graph line. How to animate the graph?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue so searched and found out about chart.js cdns they offer different types of charts and chart animations. Use Chart.js line chart it has pre-added Animation. use it from chart.js web and copy its code directly in your code.